# After Loading Page in Inspect Mode ,Shows No Internet Error.How to resolve this issue?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]
Show No internet in inspect Mode

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Right Under Network, you can see the text "Offline".
Click on that and enable Internet again.

This is a feature to allow testing what would happen if the browser lost connection to the internet. You can also use it to test what would happen if you have slow internet speed.

Answer (score 0):

In network tab you can see offline text and the red color warning /no internet logo on network tab. Just click on offline mode, select no throttling. If it's work just a up-vote.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).